# Linux の man マニュアルでリダイレクトやパイプについて調べるには？

Tags: linux, man

Linuxのマニュアルで、コマンドではないリダイレクト(>)やパイプ(|)を調べようとした際には、どのように調べたらよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

使用しているシェルの名前で man マニュアルを確認してみてください。
例えば bash なら `man bash` で以下のように説明が表示されます。

**表示例 (抜粋):**

```
シェルの文法
   パイプライン (Pipeline)
       パイプライン (pipeline)は、記号 | で区切った 1 つ以上のコマンド列です。パイプラインのフォーマットを以下に示します:

              [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ | command2 ... ]

...

リダイレクト
       シェルが解釈する特別な記法を用いると、コマンドの実行前に入出力をリダイレクトできます。
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！